# Build a JSON string for galleria in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, galleria

I need to build a JSON string to pass a list of image that I already load by an other javascript function

```
var data = [
{
    image: 'image1.jpg'
},
{
    image: 'image2.jpg'
},
{
    image: 'image3.jpg'
}
];
```

Via javascript I can create a JS object, but I need to use a key, as far as I know

```
gallimg = {};

gallimg[1] = {
    image: "image1.jpg"
};

gallimg[2] = {
    image: "image2.jpg"
};

 gallimg[3] = {
    image: "image3.jpg"
};

var gallimgjson = JSON.stringify(gallimg, null, 2);
```

Result is:

```
{
  "1": {
    "image": "image1.jpg"
  },
  "2": {
    "image": "image2.jpg"
  },
  "3": {
    "image": "image3.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gallimg` needs to be an array, and an array starts from index 0, not 1

```
var gallimg = [];

gallimg[0] = { image: "image1.jpg"};

gallimg[1] = { image: "image2.jpg"};

gallimg[2] = {image: "image3.jpg"};
```

### DRY Solution

```
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];

var gallimg = images.map(function (imageName) {
    return {'image': imageName};
});
```

Result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(gallimg, undefined, 4));`

```
[
    {
        "image": "image1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "image2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image": "image3.jpg"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];

// possible loop?
data.push(imageOBJ('image1.jpg'));
data.push(imageOBJ('image2.jpg'));
data.push(imageOBJ('image3.jpg'));
var JSONData = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

function imageOBJ(fileName){
  var self = this;
  self.image = fileName;
  return self;
}
```